# Home button on Samsung Galaxy tablet is causing my Activity to re-launch

Tags: android

On my droid phone, I get what I consider a proper pause/stop/resume/restart sequence when the home button is pressed and I then select my application. However, I'm testing on a new Samsung Galaxy tablet and when I select my application after having pressed the home button, a new activity is being launched. I do not understand why the behavior is different on the Galaxy. Any ideas? I have removed orientation config changes in the manifest, so it's not that.

Comment: I think there is no 'rules' from Google that whether the home button should/shouldn't quit the front activity. Either way, as a developer we should not consider what button cause that happen, but to implement the pause/suspend properly.

Comment: Agree that it should all be handled properly. But as you know, sometimes you have to do things differently when your activity is restarted, and I wasn't expecting the behavior I saw on the Galaxy. I was just curious as to why there might be a difference - is it the way the device is configured, or just the decision process by the OS.